# password generator code returns empty output

Tags: python, string, for-loop

password generator returns empty password list after using join and for-loop

```
import random
import string


def generate_random_password():
    characters = list(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + "!@#$%^&*()")
    length = int(input("Enter password length: "))
    password = []
    length = len(password)
    random.shuffle(characters)
    for characters in range(length):
        "".join(characters)
        password.append(characters)
        print(password)


generate_random_password()
```

Comment: the `length` variable is being set to zero with `length = len(password)`

Comment: You are printing (prefixes of?) the password, not returning anything.

Comment: You aren't *saving* the return value of `"".join` to do anything with it, and `characters` is just an integer, not a character, in the body of the loop. In short, virtually  nothing about the code after the call to `random.shuffle` is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following approach (which looks kind of the same as your approach but with some variations):

```
import random
import string

def generate_random_password():
    characters = list(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + "!@#$%^&*()")
    length_selected = int(input("Enter password length: "))
    random.shuffle(characters)
    return "".join(characters[:length_selected])
    
generate_random_password()
```

Explanation:

- The `length` variable is being overwritten with two overlapping
  statements `length = int(...)` and `length = len(password)`.
- You are using both `characters` as an iterable and an iteration across the
  range function.